# TPM (device-id 0x0, rev-id 78)

Tags: linux, tpm

I'd try to use tpm (trusted platform module) built in my laptop on Debian 8. Most of tpm_* programs gives back answer:

```
root@debian:~# tpm_takeownership 
Enter owner password: 
Confirm password: 
Enter SRK password: 
Confirm password: 
Tspi_TPM_TakeOwnership failed: 0x00000008 - layer=tpm, code=0008 (8), The TPM target command has been disabled
```

tcsd gives back:

```
root@debian:~# tcsd -f
TCSD TDDL ERROR: Could not find a device to open!
```

modules are loaded:

```
root@debian:~# lsmod | grep tpm
tpm_tis                17231  0 
tpm                    31511  2 tpm_tis
```

And finally, dmesg gives back:

```
root@debian:~# dmesg | grep tpm
[    6.743307] tpm_tis 00:05: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0x0, rev-id 78)
```

TPM is turned on in BIOS. Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a secure boot on a BeagleBone Black with an Atmel Trusted Platform Module. If you didn't find a solution, this is what I did.

I use Buildroot to create a simple Embedded Linux for the BeagleBone Black(BBB).
I added the **tpm-tools and tpm-tss** with Buildroot.

I added the following option as module:

- Hardware Random Number Generator Core support
- TPM Hardware support
- TPM Interface Specification 1.2 Interface / TPM 2.0 FIFO Interface
- TPM Interface Specification 1.2 Interface (I2C – Atmel)

I also modified my device tree for my BBB and add the following modification:

```
&i2c2 {
    tpm29:tpm@29 {
                compatible = "atmel,at97sc3204t";
                reg = <0x29>;
        };
};
```

When I start my embedded Linux on the BBB, I load the following drivers like this:

```
# modprobe tpm_i2c_atmel
# modprobe tpm_tis
# modprobe tpm_tis_core
# modprobe tpm
```

then I start the tcsd daemon like this:

```
# /usr/sbin/tcsd
```

You can make sure you see `/usr/sbin/tcsd` in the `top` / `htop` command.

After those steps, I'm able to talk to my TPM.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling the TPM in the bios may need a **power cycle** to be effective. There may be 2 different items in the bios menus to configure.

I have an extra module: `tpm_bios`.

A `device-id` of `0x0` doesn't sound right. Eg for an Atmel TPM it should be `0x3204`.

A useful first command to try is `tpm_version`, then `tpm_getpubek` and `tpm_selftest`, before `tpm_takeownership`.